# How do I get link to an image on wikipedia from the infobox?

Tags: php, wikipedia, imagesource, wikimedia-commons

I'm parsing wikipedia infoboxes and I noticed that some infoboxes have image fields - these fields hold names of image files stashed on wikipedia somewhere. However they just contain the name of the file as is as opposed to the actual link.

I checked the links of the images on real live infoboxes and the links do not seem to be from one source but the sources vary. How can I hyperlink to an image on wikipedia considering I only have the name of the image from an infobox entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:filename.jpg` ? Even if the files are located on Wikimedia Commons, the above URL should still work.

Edit: Are you trying to hotlink the image? If so, Wikipedia prohibits hotlinking.  http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia#Hotlinking

**Update 10-Jan-2019:** Hotlinking is [now permitted](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia#Downloading):

> **Hotlinking or InstantCommons**: It is possible to use files directly on
>   Commons within another website, by setting up a MediaWiki wiki with
>   InstantCommons, ...

Answer (score 12):

According to [What are the strangely named components in Wikipedia file paths](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_strangely_named_components_in_file_paths.3F), you need to run md5 to find out url. Now wikipedia allows hotlinking, so:

If you have utf-8 encoded `$name`, you need to do the following:

```
$filename = replace($name, ' ', '_');
$digest = md5($filename);
$folder = $digest[0] . '/' . $digest[0] . $digest[1] . '/' .  urlencode($filename);
$url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/' . $folder;
```

The same can be used for thumbnails.

Comment: Thanx, this works well. I have translated your answer to JS.

Comment: @Yuri Baburov http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/ is not fixed some time this link https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/Cruciblecover.jpg any idea how to get dynamic url?

Comment: Note that the approach in this answer is now outdated and overly complex, as Wikimedia sites currently provide much more friendly URL scheme for hotlinking. For example, you can use `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Example.jpg` to hotlink image "Example.jpg". Please see answers below for more details.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a simpler way to hotlink the files on Wikipedia using the [Special:FilePath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath) page. Hence, if you want to link the file Example.jpg on English Wikipedia, you can use `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Example.jpg`.

Similar links should work for other Wikimedia Foundation sites (e. g. Wikimedia Commons).

Details and recommendations regarding hotlinking can be found on Wikimedia's [Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia/technical#Hotlinking).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a JavaScript implementation of a working PHP answer (credits to Yuri Baburov):

```
var name = "filename.jpg";
var filename = name.replace(/ /g, "_"); 
var digest = md5(filename);
var folder = digest[0] + '/' + digest[0] + digest[1] + '/' + encodeURIComponent(filename);
var url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/' + folder;
```

Note that you must include external `md5()` function (https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-MD5); it is not native to JS.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the URL prefix should be:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/
```

Moreover the folder must contain the repeated name of the file with a size specified as prefix:

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/d/dd/Ruins-imperial-complex-milan-.jpg/220px-Ruins-imperial-complex-milan-.jpg

$filename = replace($name, ' ', '_');
$digest = md5($filename);
$urlencfile =  urlencode($filename)
$imgwidth = 220
$folder = $digest[0] . '/' . $digest[0] . $digest[1] . '/' . $urlencfile . '/' . $imgwidth . 'px-' . $urlencfile;
$url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/' . $folder;
```