# Getting links to wikipedia images

Tags: python, mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to extract the links to all the images in the wikipedia, without losing the image names and probably the alt tags. I got to know from

[How do I get link to an image on wikipedia from the infobox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026337/how-do-i-get-link-to-an-image-on-wikipedia-from-the-infobox)

that I could get it by querying: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:filename.jpg 
However, to do this I need to get all the filenames of the images. 
Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: I've got freebase working to get me images using the GUID, however certain topics in freebase has no images. So, that's a problem unlike wikipedia.

Comment: I think this will help.. http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/WEX/Documentation#Tables just reading it!

Comment: Do you need the images on a given page? The images in the infobox on a given page? All the images on Wikipedia?

Comment: are you sure you want all those images?? there are too many of them

Comment: The images in the infobox is good enough. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3):

this gives the list of all image urls and file names also in the page

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=World&generator=images&gimlimit=10&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime&format=json
```

change the title= part

Comment: How come it doesn't give me relevant results? Try.. title=google

Comment: Did you have resolve this problem? Why there are so much images useless?

Comment: @madCode https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=google&generator=images&gimlimit=10&prop=imageinfo&iiprop=url|dimensions|mime&format=json seems to work fine